# With React Navigation in React Native, how do I correctly pass navigaion.navigate arguments with params that are handled by a function and dictionary?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-typescript

I'm using React Navigation in React Native with TyepScript for app development.

In the frontend I have many screens set up to be navigated to according to an input I am supposed to receive from the backend (formToShow). For this, I set up a function that handles the navigation with said requirement:

```js
export const HomeApiRedirector = (
  formToShow: number,
  account: number,
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<ScreensList, keyof ScreensList, "StackNavigation">
) => {
  const homeRedirectorIndex: { [key: number]: keyof ScreensList } = {
    1: "MainWalletView",
    2: "MainWalletViewByHolder",
    3: "MainFixedTerms",
    4: "MainFuturesCommodities",
    5: "MainFuturesFC",
    6: "MainSecurities",
    7: "MainSecuritiesByCurrency",
    8: "MainSecuritiesByHolder",
    9: "MainOptions",
    10: "TransfersWalletView",
    11: "TransfersWalletView",
    12: "TransfersFixedTerms",
    13: "TransfersFuturesCommodities",
    14: "TransfersFuturesFC",
    15: "TransfersSecurities",
    16: "TransfersSecurities",
    17: "TransfersSecurities",
    18: "TransfersOptions",
    19: "TransfersOperationsFC",
  };

  if (formToShow in homeRedirectorIndex === false) {
    Alert("Error", "Navigation to screen failed. No such screen exists.");
    return;
  }

  navigation.navigate(homeRedirectorIndex[formToShow], { idAccount: account });
};
```

However, I'm getting an error that I believe is saying that I neeed to explicitly name the arguments instead of passing a function.

[image]

```
Argument of type '[keyof ScreensList, { idAccount: number; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[screen: "SignIn"] | [screen: "SignIn", params: undefined] | [screen: "ResetPassword"] | [screen: "ResetPassword", params: undefined] | [screen: "PasswordCode"] | [screen: "PasswordCode", params: { user: string; } | undefined] | [screen: "ContactUs"] | ... 74 more ... | [screen: ...]'.
  Type '[keyof ScreensList, { idAccount: number; }]' is not assignable to type '[screen: "MovementsOperationsFC", params: undefined]'.
    Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
      Type 'keyof ScreensList' is not assignable to type '"TransfersOperationsFC"'.
        Type '"SignIn"' is not assignable to type '"TransfersOperationsFC"'.
```

I've tried using a type assertion `homeRedirectorIndex[formToDisplay] as never` and it temporarily fixes it, but if I'm passing params throught navigation then it doesn't work anymore. And it definitely does not solve it correctly, it works more like a workaround.

This is my ScreensList navigation object:

```js
export type ScreensList = {
  SignIn: undefined;
  ResetPassword: undefined;
  PasswordCode: { user: string } | undefined;
  ContactUs: undefined;
  AboutUs: undefined;
  (... 70+ more)
};
```

How can I correctly type this navigation method?